# Javascript: SyntaxError: missing variable name

Tags: javascript

I keep getting `SyntaxError: missing variable name` on my line 17: `var drawSverige = document.getElementById('draw-sverige')`

I can't seem to figure out why. It clearly states "var" right before the word drawSverige.

```
!function () {
    'use strict';

    function flag(){
        this.init = function (flag, country){
            this.flagInfo = country
            this.htmlTag = flag
               }
      }

        this.draw = function() {
            this.htmlTag.innerHTML = this.flagInfo
        };


        var flagSverige = document.getElementById('flag-sverige'),
        var drawSverige = document.getElementById('draw-sverige'),

        var flagElfenbenskusten = document.getElementById('flag-elfenbenskusten'),
        var drawElfenbenskusten = document.getElementById('draw-elfenbenskusten'),

        var flagMaruritius = document.getElementById('flag-maruritius'),
        var drawMaruritius = document.getElementById('draw-maruritius'),

        var flagJapan = document.getElementById('flag-japan'),
        var drawJapan = document.getElementById('draw-japan'),

        showSverige = new flag;
        showSverige.init(flag, '<div class="flagga1 sverige"><div class="box1"></div><div class="box2"></div><div class="box3"></div><div class="box4"></div></div>');

        var showElfenbenskusten = new flag;
        showElfenbenskusten.init(flag, '<div class="flag elfenbenskusten"><div class="part1"></div><div class="part2"></div></div>');

        var showMaruritius = new flag;
        showMaruritius.init(flag, '<div class="flagga2 maruritius"><div class="box1"></div><div class="box2"></div><div class="box3"></div><div class="box4"></div><div class="box5"></div></div>');

        var showJapan = new flag;
        showJapan.init(flag, '<div class="flagga3 japan"><div class="box1"></div><div class="cirkel1"></div></div>');

        for (var flagx = [
            flagSverige,
            flagElfenbenskusten,
            flagMaruritius,
            flagJapan
            ], tot = 0; tot < flagx.length; tot++)
            flagx[tot].draw();

}();
```

Comment: Why are you ending your lines with commas instead of semicolons? If you're going to use commas to declare multiple `var`s on one line you only need the `var` keyword once. What you have is invalid syntax.

Comment: Either you define each variable with `var` or separate them with commas, but you can't do both.

Comment: (Off-topic remark: this data structure would be wiser to implement using a single array/object instead of multiple individual variables anyway.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using `comma` after the declaration so remove `var` keyword after the first one like

```
 var flagSverige = document.getElementById('flag-sverige'),
        drawSverige = document.getElementById('draw-sverige'),

        flagElfenbenskusten = document.getElementById('flag-elfenbenskusten'),
        drawElfenbenskusten = document.getElementById('draw-elfenbenskusten'),

       flagMaruritius = document.getElementById('flag-maruritius'),
       drawMaruritius = document.getElementById('draw-maruritius'),

       flagJapan = document.getElementById('flag-japan'),
       drawJapan = document.getElementById('draw-japan');
```

Answer (score 0):

Each of your variables have a comma at the end.

Replace the ',' with a ';' and you should be fixed up.